# Fetch data stored in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New here, wanted to know how to fetch the data from a particular URL and store the respective in a database and later access it using Rails.

However, I was able to fetch the data from a URL and received the data in XML format and was able to display it, but that was being done manually, all I want to know is how do I get the data from URL, as it is in Hash form and contains a lot of attributes.

Need to store those attributes in database and retrieve the value from URL directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for that use Nokogiri gem for more information you can read from http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

I also gives you following commands of nokogiri... please avoide # sign

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(your site url))
# get all specific selector's all matching elements
# doc.css("div")

# get specific selector's first matching element
# doc.at_css("div")

# get matching element by id name
# doc.at_css("input#id name")
# eg: doc.at_css("input#ResultsCount")

# get matching element by class name
# doc.at_css("div.class name")
# eg: doc.at_css("div.results")


# File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/aa.txt","w+").write(doc.css("div#search-result-listings"))

# get fields data eg. take a value of input field whose id ResultsCount
# <input type="hidden" name="ResultsCount" id="ResultsCount" value="12321" />
# doc.at_css("input#ResultsCount")["value"]

# get all results
# search_results=doc.at_css("div#search-result-listings").css("div.result.clearfix")


#find by tag ("<ul>") and find their elements and children
dc=doc.at_css("div#search-result-listings")
#find all elements of ul such as li with their childs
dc.at_css("ul").elements
#if only childs of elements
dc.at_css("ul").elements.children
#if you want to print that child value then use "text" property
dc.at_css("ul").elements.children[0].text
#if you want all child data then use
dc.at_css("ul").elements.children.text
or
dc.at_css("ul").elements.text
or
dc.at_css("ul").text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch page using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html), parse content using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html) and build XML from received data using [Nokogiri::XML::Builder](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) (or [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/)) or store it in database.